# Batch Graph API in iOS SDK 3.1.1

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to understand how to create a batch of **dependent** Graph API calls using iOS SDK 3.1.1.  There are plenty of samples online for independent batches but nothing for batches where subsequent calls require output of prior calls.

It looks as if some support is built into the FBRequestConnection class since you can `addRequest` and specify an optional `batchEntryName`, but I do not understand how to reference the values returned in subsequent requests?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.